# read whole document and match one part in python

Tags: python

My question is, how would I compare a username and password two a whole document to find if it is in there. so far I have this:

```
regorlog = raw_input("press 1 to register, press 2 to log in! \n")

if regorlog == "1":
    uname = raw_input("what is your desired username?\n")
    pwd = raw_input("what is your desired password?\n")
    pwd2 = raw_input("please retype your password\n")
    if (pwd == pwd2):
        file = open("userlog.txt", "a")
        file.write(uname + " || " + pwd + "\n")
        file.close()
    else:
        print 'sorry, those passwords do not match'
elif regorlog == "2":
    loguname = raw_input("what is your username? \n")
    logpwd = raw_input("what is your password? \n")
    file = open("userlog.txt", "r")
        #here, I need to read the file userlog.txt, and look and see if the username and password combination exists in the file somewhere.
        file.close()
```

I am having trouble reading the whole file, and looking for the username and password combo. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: don't store passwords in a file.

Comment: @RyanHaining: Or at least encrypt them. The main problem is what happens when a username or password contains "||"!

Comment: @Veedrac the end result will hopefully be a base to test different types of incryption, I would just like to get this working to start

Comment: don't encrypt them, hash them (with salt!) look into one-way hash functions

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a built-in module to do this for you:

```
import shelve

regorlog = raw_input("press 1 to register, press 2 to log in! \n")

if regorlog == "1":
    uname = raw_input("what is your desired username?\n")
    pwd = raw_input("what is your desired password?\n")
    pwd2 = raw_input("please retype your password\n")
    if pwd == pwd2:
        shelf = shelve.open("userlog.txt", "c")
        shelf[uname] = pwd
        shelf.close()
    else:
        print 'sorry, those passwords do not match'
elif regorlog == "2":
    loguname = raw_input("what is your username? \n")
    logpwd = raw_input("what is your password? \n")

    shelf = shelve.open("userlog.txt", "c")
    try:
        matched = shelf[loguname] == logpwd
    except KeyError:
        matched = False
    shelf.close()

    print 'Matched: ', matched
```

Edit: fixed. I suggest changing the name of the file, though

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. here is what I ended up doing!

```
regorlog = raw_input("press 1 to register, press 2 to log in! \n")

if regorlog == "1":
    uname = raw_input("what is your desired username?\n")
    pwd = raw_input("what is your desired password?\n")
    pwd2 = raw_input("please retype your password\n")
    if (pwd == pwd2):
        file = open("userlog.txt", "a")
        file.write(uname + " || " + pwd + "\n")
        file.close()
    else:
        print 'sorry, those passwords do not match'
elif regorlog == "2":
    loguname = raw_input("what is your username? \n")
    logpwd = raw_input("what is your password? \n")
    file = open("userlog.txt", "r")
    if loguname + " || " + logpwd in open('userlog.txt').read():
        print "true"
    file.close()
```

Comment: This won't always work. Say you have user "ab", password "xy" and another user "abc", password "xyz".

Comment: Do you see the problem with your test?  Say the user name is `Fred` and the password is `thisisahardpasswordtoguess`.  All I have to do to crack the system is guess that the password is `t`, because `"Fred || t"` is a substring of `"Fred || thisisahardpasswordtoguess"`.  In fact, come to think of it, if you simply hit return, you can crack **everyone's** account!

Comment: Also username " ||", password ""; username "", password "|| ".

Comment: @DSM you where actually correct. is there any way to only print true if it matches the whole string?

Comment: @user2744763 I modified your ending to look for an exact match in my answer

Comment: @RyanHaining thank you so much for your supportive adition!! I have added the code, and all looks good, but whatever I do, it prints false. Any insight you have on the matter would be much apreceated. Also, thank you all for your patience, a am a programming noob.

Answer (score 0):

change the last part in what you have to:

```
# ...
elif regorlog == "2":
    loguname = raw_input("what is your username? \n")
    logpwd = raw_input("what is your password? \n")

    login_info = loguname + " || " + logpwd
    with open("userlog.txt", "r") as users_file: # closes the file automatically
        if any(login_info == line.rstrip() for line in users_file):
            # if any line in the file matches
            print "true"
```

But for the love of security please don't store passwords as plaintext

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: @user2744763 sorry, forgot a `.rstrip()`